# Exponential Precision [print double, tiny number]

Tags: java, precision, exponential

Is there a way of printing with EXPONENTIAL PRECISION ? 
I need to fill up some data with tiny numbers and compare those after....

I have like this:

```
(0) - Mesured estimatedTime for multithread in block: 1.4917951E16 s
(1) - Mesured estimatedTime for multithread in block: 7.531891E15 s
(2) - Mesured estimatedTime for multithread in block: 2.9287E13 s
(3) - Mesured estimatedTime for multithread in block: 3.28478435E17 s
(4) - Mesured estimatedTime for multithread in block: 6.038E12 s
```

And i want to print like this:

```
(0) - Mesured estimatedTime for original in block: 0000.15595175E15 s           
(1) - Mesured estimatedTime for original in block: 0007.335638E15 s             
(2) - Mesured estimatedTime for original in block: 0416.66E15 s                 
(3) - Mesured estimatedTime for original in block: 0000.0390156852E15 s         
(4) - Mesured estimatedTime for original in block: 6642.0E15 s
```

I know that you can force it like this:

```
// Force minimum number of digits to left and right of decimal point
formatter = new DecimalFormat("0.0E0");
s = formatter.format(-1234.567);         // -1.2E3
```

But don't know how i can force it to Expo-Precision :((((
help!! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you want to imply a precision of 1e15.

```
for (double d : new double[]{1.4917951E16, 7.531891E15, 2.9287E13, 3.28478435E17, 6.038E12})
    System.out.printf("%11fE15%n", d/1e15);
```

prints

```
  14.917951E15
   7.531891E15
   0.029287E15
 328.478435E15
   0.006038E15
```

If the range is much wider you can use DecimalFormat

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(300);
df.setGroupingUsed(false);
for(double d = 1 ; d <= 1e30; d *= 1e5) {
    System.out.println(df.format(d/1e15)+"E15");
}
```

prints

```
0.000000000000001E15
0.0000000001E15
0.00001E15
1E15
100000E15
10000000000E15
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! :-) Have being looking for this all morning!! :** s2

Comment: The printf is the simplest format but may not be what you want. For example I suspect `1` will be turned into `1e-15e15` ;) Hopefully you get the idea and can use DecimalFormat or other to suit your needs.

Comment: Peter Lawrey do you know if theres any way using DecimalFormat ? I didn't find any for these proupose... that printf solves my problem but i guess isnt the best solution.. right?

Comment: Added a DeciamlFormat example.